# How is the final type result of a generic utility type displayed in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I used the following code, but I can't obtain the final type of type A in the editor. The editor always displays the composite form of the generic utility, making it hard to check the type output while writing code. Is there a way to force TypeScript to calculate the final type result and present it in the editor?

```
import type {GetKeyOf} from "typescript-treasure"
interface EmitterMasterEventMap
{
    [p: string]: never;
}

type A = GetKeyOf<EmitterMasterEventMap>[]; // How do I obtain the final type of type A in the editor?
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't rely on third-party libraries unless you have specific questions about those libraries.  I don't know what "typescript-treasure" is; could you copy whatever `GetKeyOf`'s definition out of that library and into your example code?

Comment: Please see prev comment. TS doesn't guarantee how types are displayed; there have been various feature requests, see [ms/TS#34556](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34556) and [ms/TS#47980](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47980). Depending on the use case one might try something like the answer to [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218). But in your specific situation I'd be inclined to write an intersection like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wjoZvN) shows. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer post; id not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz I believe I have indeed obtained the necessary information, please draft the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't make any guarantees about how types are *displayed* in IntelliSense, nor does it really let you tweak the display explicitly.  There are various open feature requests in GitHub that would enable this if implemented, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#34556](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34556) and [microsoft/TypeScript#47980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47980). People interested in seeing this happen might want to go to those issues, give them a , and possibly comment describing their use case if it is more compelling than what's already there. Pragmatically speaking it's unlikely to happen either way, as there hasn't been a lot of activity there.

So you might want to rewrite the type so that it displays the way you want. There's no one-size-fits-all solution that doesn't have weird edge cases, so I'd probably just tailor the type to the particular use case here.  Since `GetKeyOf` seems to return keylike types (some subtype of `string | number | symbol`) and none of those are nullish, you can just [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) that type with the empty object type `{}`, and this will generally make the compiler try to more fully evaluate the type when displaying it:

```
type A = (GetKeyOf<EmitterMasterEventMap> & {})[];
// type A = (string | number)[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nA4imBpFRAeQDM4BfOEqCEOAIiVQGcBjKYMGAWhihQCGzAK796AKGAA7GCigkBrNAFEQwGLKgBZIZuUA3FDJ1gM4uBbgBtMAC44zPtIDmAXXtSUhqAG5x5cXEmNABBOABeOAAKHHxCUgAeVXVNHUc5AyMYEwA+OAAyDHIASitXPwB6CoRkUIjoxw4pZzgAHzgpYRAAIzlS13EgA)